# Isinglass and temperature

Tags: temperature, wine, fining, isinglass

The wine kit that I am making uses isinglass for fining and recommends storing the wine at 70 degrees during the process. In the past I've used gelatin in my beers to clear and I know that it works better when stored cold. Does this hold true for isinglass? Or should I still store the recommended 70 degrees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this, 70 sounds good.  Around 60 is recommended for beer.

http://www.practicalbrewing.co.uk/main/fining/page5.html